# How can I write my context-free grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I'm trying to write a CFG over the alphabet `Σ = {a,b}` for all words starting and ending with the same number of `a`'s, with at least one `b` in the middle.

Now I understand the basic concept of CFG, variables, production rules, etc. Unfortunately I've run out of ideas for writing the aforementioned CFG. All I've got so far is

```
S → aYXYa
X → XbX | b | λ
Y → ???
```

I *think* that the production rules `S` and `X` will give me a string with two **`a`**s on both sides with as many **`b`**s in the middle as I'd like. However, I'm not sure how I can also put as many **`a`**s on both sides of the **`b`**s while making sure there are exactly the same number of **`a`**s on each side.

Any suggestions, solutions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To make sure there there are the same number of a's on each side, just make sure your production rules always have matched a's.

Comment: Hi Albert, could you please give an example? Thanks

Comment: The rule "X → XbX | b | λ" is more complicated than necessary, but yes, it does create any number of b's.

Comment: Matched a's similar to your production rule for S. Whenever you generate an a, end with an a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
S → aSa | B
B → b | bB
```

This should be the CFG you're looking for. Whenever you're dealing with the same thing on the beginning and end, remember that you can't guarantee that the same var will be filled the same way. As such, you have to make those explicit.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can finally move on. :)

Comment: Don't mention it. I'm having my own fun with Intro to Theoretical Computer Science (as my uni likes to call it)

Comment: Haha. Wish you all the best! :)

Answer (score 7):

As an ex-professor who's taught this class before, I'm not going to give you the answer. I will, however, give you a hint:

You have the right idea to break it into two parts, the a's and the rest. However, you're not doing either one of them right.

First try writing: a<sup>n</sup>ba<sup>n</sup>  then branch off from there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you mean my rules should first accommodate as many balanced a's on either side before placing any b's in the middle?

Comment: Well, I meant you should write S = aSa | b first... then figure out the 2nd line... but yeah...

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since my CS undergrad days but this looks reasonable:

S -> aSa | bX

X -> bX | E

Basically, you start with S and add as many pairs of a's as you want and then switch to X and add as many b's as you want.

Comment: DBendit beat me by 6 seconds :)

Comment: No worries, thank you for your answer as well. I've slightly modified both your solutions so that the start variable only accepts a's on both sides with an extra variable (a bit of repetition) to allow the addition of further a's and b's. :)